# How to get rid of session params from KeyCloak

Tags: keycloak, openid, keycloak-connect

Im using KeyCloak and openid connect. My KeyCloak is running in the development mode.

I would like to get rid of the session url paramters, is that possible?

Here is an example : [Example Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXXgp.png)

I tried some changes in Keycloak, but it didnt work and I also didnt find much on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

Beforehand : Im using vue as a framework.

I rerouted on my page via :

```
<a href="/">
```

I now tried the intergrated router component for rerouting.

```
<router-link to="/Dashboard">Dashboard</router-link>
```

and voila no more.

Solution is not to redirect via href="xx".